# Codeigniter 4 error en servidor

Tags: servidor, codeigniter-4, error500

saludos espero se encuentren todos bien, bendiciones y que la iluminación los acompañe siempre'.
Tengo un enrrollo grande actualmente, les cuento tengo un proyecto asignado donde estoy trabajando, algo pequeño un programa de información y de reportes en codeigniter, estoy recien iniciado en el framework
ok en contexto, tengo el proyecto ya entorno, registre un usuario nuevo en la base de datos pero no me deja lograr iniciar session me da un error de post

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 4ms]

Tengo habilitado el metodo de desarrollo para ver los log de errores pero no logro hacer que se muestren soy nuevo en este framework y mi experiencia es corta en programación pero si estoy empapado de información y conocimiento me pueden asesorar aquí¡

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, podrías compartir una imagen de lo que te aparece en la pestaña de response que está en tu herramienta de desarrollo web, en tu caso donde dice `Respuesta` en esa misma ventana de red, saludos.